# Write to non existing file with Files using Java 7

Tags: java, file, path, java-7

Hi I try to write to non existing file

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Path newFile = Paths.get("output.txt");
        Files.write(newFile, "Sample text".getBytes());
}
```

And everything is OK but if I put option

```
Files.write(newFile, "Sample text".getBytes(),StandardOpenOption.DELETE_ON_CLOSE);
```

An error appears

```
Exception in thread "main" java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: problem.txt
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(Unknown Source)
```

So to work I have to add option

```
StandardOpenOption.CREATE_NEW
```

Why in the second attempt with `StandardOpenOption.DELETE_ON_CLOSE` doesn't work but the first without any option works and creates file?

I am using java version(build 1.7.0_45-b18)

Comment: please post the full code. Also, which JVM platform are you using?

Comment: How can the OS delete a file that does not exist yet?

Comment: Edited with full example

Comment: What were you trying to achieve by writing a file and deleting it before anyone else ever gets a chance to read it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [documentation for `Files.write`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#write(java.nio.file.Path,%20byte[],%20java.nio.file.OpenOption...)):

> If no options are present then this method works as if the [`CREATE`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/StandardOpenOption.html#CREATE), [`TRUNCATE_EXISTING`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/StandardOpenOption.html#TRUNCATE_EXISTING), and [`WRITE`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/StandardOpenOption.html#WRITE) options are present

So, once you start specifying `OpenOption`s, you have to specify the options you need from those three as well (or as you already noted, `CREATE_NEW` instead of `CREATE`).

Comment: Note: Because this is `Files.write`, `WRITE` is likely assumed even if left out.

Comment: Had TRANCATE_EXISTING and WRITE specified, but no CREATE. From your answer, I left out the options or wrote all three, the problem is gone. So thanks.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/StandardOpenOption.html)

public static final `StandardOpenOption DELETE_ON_CLOSE`
Delete on close. When this option is present then the implementation makes a best effort attempt to delete the file when closed by the appropriate close method. If the close method is not invoked then a best effort attempt is made to delete the file when the Java virtual machine terminates (either normally, as defined by the Java Language Specification, or where possible, abnormally). This option is primarily intended for use with work files that are used solely by a single instance of the Java virtual machine. This option is not recommended for use when opening files that are open concurrently by other entities. Many of the details as to when and how the file is deleted are implementation specific and therefore not specified. In particular, an implementation may be unable to guarantee that it deletes the expected file when replaced by an attacker while the file is open. Consequently, security sensitive applications should take care when using this option.

**So how are supposed to delete a file that does not exist ?**